# Responsive Design: How to expand vertically list item (twitter ticker)?

Tags: jquery, css, responsive-design

I've created a twitter feed to put on a website. You can see the feed here: [anibalcascais.com/tweet/twitter.html](http://anibalcascais.com/tweet/twitter.html)

I'm trying to make the feed responsive. So far, the surrounding div is responsive.
The problem is when the browser window is resized to ipad/iphone size, the `li` element doesn't resize and some tweets are cut short.

How can I make the `ul` and `li` expand to acomodate either one line or two lines tweets?

Thank You

Answer (score 0):

you have the following regarding height:

```
.tweet_list {
    height: 28px;
}
```

instead of setting the height of the ul explicitly so it shows only the first li, I'd try something like:

```
.tweetlist>li {display: none;}
.tweetlist>li:first-child {
   display: block;
 }
```

that way you can let the ul autosize to the size of the first in your current list which will make it work for both 1 and 2 line-sized tweet-li's

Comment: ok, the code you kindly provided seems to do the trick. The only problem is taht it works for the first feed item. As soon as the next feed slides in, it disappears... (working link at original post) Thank You!

Comment: hm, I tested in firefox which has it work fine, looking a bit further adding .tweetlist { min-height: 28px;} fixes it for opera, but it still doesn't quite do the correct thing in chrome

Comment: chrome doens't reapply the css :first-child when it changes as you shuffle the first list item to last place

Comment: I see that in firefox it works fine. Thanks for pointing that :)

Comment: I'm gonna take a look at possible alternatives to this. Thank you for help :)